# How do I get my iOS5 iPhone 4 (and 3GS) to play a .wav file attachment in email?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I have a phone service that sends me emails of voicemails in .wav files as attachments.  How do I get them to play on my iPhone 4 (and 3GS)?

Comment: How big is the wav file? If you add it to iTunes can you play it on your device?

Answer (score 1):

In Mail, just tap on the attachment to play the .wav file.

Comment: When I do that, it presents the modal view with Quicktime in it, attempts to play it and dismisses the modal view immediately.

Comment: Is this behavior isolated to this phone system and the way it encodes .WAVs files? Have you tested with an alternate source / provider of .WAV files?

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good solution, but it should work.

Once you send the file to your Mac (or Windows machine), and put it in iTunes, you can convert to iPhone-compatible format and sync back to your iPhone... Here is the iTunes menu choice for "Create and iPod or iPhone Version":

[image]

Comment: If you have to send the file to a Mac, then the story is over, you can easily play the file on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess as I have never had to play audio files not compatible on my phone but try getting an external app that could possibly read it such as Dropbox and in the message, tap open with -> dropbox.

If that doesn't work, its in your dropbox so you could open it on another device that can play .wav files.

Hope this helps!